# GRUB is installed, but I can't see Ubuntu - HELP!

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

My computer is a ThinkPad X1 Carbon (Windows 10 is installed by default). I dual-booted Ubuntu, but after its installation, my computer brought me back to Windows 10. Even if I know that Ubuntu is installed, I can't get access that OS. I am pretty sure I installed GRUB (in /dev/nvme0n1p5), but I can't find it.

Could anyone be able to tell me what I have to do to find out where is Ubuntu?

Thanks in advance!

**P.S.** I think GRUB is installed, but I can't see it.

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI or BIOS boot mode? But either way you always install to drive not to a partition. If UEFI it would have correctly installed. If BIOS, youdo not have grub anywhere that will allow you to boot. May be best to see details, you can run from Ubuntu live installer or any working install:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: I can't give you details from BootInfo, since I don't even access to Ubuntu. It is installed, but I haven't access to Ubuntu and GRUB. How do I know If I installed Ubuntu on a partition? What different does it make if I installed Ubuntu with UEFI or BIOS boot mode? I'm pretty sure I install Ubuntu with UEFI.

Comment: Run the live installer and add Boot-Repair to it.

Comment: Do you have 2 mins?

Comment: In fact, I found my problem, but I can't resolve it. The system can detect a bootloader, but I don't know how to access GRUB when I restart the system. In fact, I cannot see GRUB since yesterday even if it is installed. Could you help me at this point?

Comment: Need to see details from Summary Report. Also this issue: Installing GNU/Linux on a 2014 Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon UEFI/BIOS suspend to RAM issue
http://mako.cc/copyrighteous/installing-gnulinux-on-an-2014-lenovo-thinkpad-x1-carbon